# Inno Setup: Do not (re)create a shortcut if it already exist

Tags: inno-setup

I want to add a shortcut only if it doesn't exist yet.

Similarlu to `onlyifdoesntexist` flag from `Files` section, which does not exist in `Icons` section.

Is there a way to do this without adding code in `Code` section?

I tried

```
[Icons]
Name:"{userdesktop}\HotKey\link-to-program";Filename:"{app}\program.exe";HotKey:"Ctrl+Shift+f"
Name:"{userdesktop}\link-to-program"; Filename:"{app}\program.exe"
```

But that fails in this section.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
[Icons]  
  Name: "{userdesktop}\HotKey\link-to-program"; Filename:"{app}\program.exe"; \  
    Check: Not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\HotKey\link-to-program.lnk'))
```

([`FileExists`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) is built in, so you don't need to declare it).

---

I also marked that folder as hidden to achieve my goal to have an extra shortcut that is not accessible by the user (as commented in the question), but this is not necessary for the solution itself`.

```
[Dirs]  
  Name: "{userdesktop}\HotKey"; Attribs: hidden system
```